# Python Regex - get words around match

Tags: python, regex

I want to get the words before and after my match. I could use `string.split(' ')` - but as I already use regex, isn't there a much better way using only regex?

Using a match object, I can get the exact location. However, this location is character indexed.

```
import re

myString = "this. is 12my90\nExample string"
pattern = re.compile(r"(\b12(\w+)90\b)",re.IGNORECASE |  re.UNICODE)

m = pattern.search(myString)
print("Hit: "+m.group())
print("Indix range: "+str(m.span()))
print("Words around match: "+myString[m.start()-1:m.end()+1]) # should be +/-1 in _words_, not characters
```

Output:

> Hit: 12my90 Indix
>
> range: (9, 15)
>
> Words around match:  12my90

For getting the matching word and the word before, I tried:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(\b(w+)\b)\s(\b12(\w+)90\b)",re.IGNORECASE | 
re.UNICODE)
```

Which yields no matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second pattern you have to escape the `w+` like `\w+`.

Apart from that, there is a newline in your example which you can match using another following `\s`

Your pattern with 3 capturing groups might look like

```
(\b\w+\b)\s(\b12\w+90\b)\s(\b\w+\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A6629V/1)

You could use the capturing groups to get the values

```
print("Words around match: " + m.group(1) + " " + m.group(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

new line character is missing

```
regx = r"(\w+)\s12(\w+)90\n(\w+)"
```

Comment: `\s` includes the linefeed.